# IdentityServer4: Why does a URL in ClientCorsOrigins table give unauthorized_client error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, identityserver4

So recently I have started getting
`Sorry, there was an error : unauthorized_client Unknown client or client not enabled`
when attempting to authenticate against Identity Server. After a lot of digging I found that it was because the client had a URL registered in ClientCorsOrigins table and not an origin.

from Identityserver docs

> Be sure to use an origin (not a URL) when configuring CORS. For
> example: https://foo:123/ is a URL, whereas https://foo:123 is an
> origin.

However up until very recently the same URL had been in the table and it never complained. Has something changed in identity server 4 recently?

Comment: Remove the / at the end of the URL in the ClientCorsOrigins table? origin that you do your request from must match the ones listed in the table exactly. (without / at the end). What does your URL look like when it does not work?

Comment: it had always been this http://example.net/someappname.. and it never gave any errors until a few days ago.. but as soon I renamed to http://example.net it stopped giving the error.

Comment: Yes, example.net is the origin and that is what you need to approve, the path is not part of the origin, only scheme+domain+port is.

Comment: @ToreNestenius, true. but previously i had the URL and not origin in there and it never gave an error. around late friday we started getting 'unauthorized_client' error all of a sudden, and just this morning i found out that the cause was the url. so maybe folks at identityserver pushed out some updates that i'm not aware of. in any case, the error it self isn't very helpful in pinpointing what actually was responsible for the error, in fact its misleading to say the least.

Comment: IdentityServer4, version 4 was released last Friday.